Conditional Probability of Byte Being Smaller Than the Max in a Sequence
I have the following byte sequence.

$X, A, B_1, \ldots, B_h$ are discrete i.i.d. random values in $[0,255]$.
I want to simplify the probability
$$
P(X < \max(A,B_1,\ldots,B_{h-1})\mid\max(B_1,\ldots,B_h)=m)
$$
Obviously, the expectation of $\frac{h-1}{h}$ of the bytes in $A,B_1,\ldots,B_{h-1}$ is influenced by knowing $\max(B_1,\ldots,B_h)=m$.
I just cannot wrap my head around how exactly.
Intuitively, I wanna say that $\frac{h-1}{h}$ of the sequence has a $\frac{h-1}{h}$ chance of having value $m$ (because if it's not, then it's $B_h$). But as we are moving on a discrete value range, both $B_h$ and $\max(B_1,\ldots,B_{h-1})$ can be equal to $m$.
So this leaves me very confused.
I don't want a final solution, I don't actually want to solve this probability conclusively, but just express this event in an alternative way that is easier for me to think about.
I hope somebody can help <3
